# How to make a Slash header in Grid?

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts

Here is an example,

```
Grid[Transpose@Insert[Transpose@Insert[Table[aaa,
      {ab, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}}, {ϕ, {0, π/
        4, π/2, (3 π)/4, π}}], {0, π/4, π/2, (
      3 π)/4, π}, 1], {Grid[{{"\\", ϕ}, {"x:y", "\\"}}], 
    "1:1", "1:2", "1:3", "2:3"}, 1], Frame -> All]
```

it gives
[image]

Notice the ugly slash header? That is because I don't know how to do it, so I do it ugly. I want a perfect slash separate "x:y" and "$\phi$", and maybe even multi-slash header.

---

**edit**

I temporarily accept Graumagier's answer, though like Kuba said "it is like an acrobatic". But it works and has some sort of flexibility, because the header is now a graphic, we can move the labels around using drawing tools for graphics for better appearance and also resize the size of the slash header easily by just dragging the graphic border. Finally, better solutions are welcome :)

**Updata**

write a function that generate a slash header graphic to make life easier.

```
Clear[corner];
corner[rowlabel_, columnlabel_, ratioofhtow_, fontsize_: Larger] := 
 Module[{heightvec = {0, ratioofhtow}, widthvec = {1, 0}}, 
  Graphics[{Line[{heightvec, widthvec}], 
    Text[Style[rowlabel, "StandardForm", fontsize], 
     0.5*(heightvec + widthvec) - 0.25*heightvec], 
    Text[Style[columnlabel, "StandardForm", fontsize], 
     0.5*(heightvec + widthvec) + 0.25*widthvec]}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Tiny]]
```

So now

[image]

Comment: `TableForm` might give a more pleasant output. Try `TableForm[
 Table[aaa, {ab, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 
     3}}}, {\[Phi], {0, \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/2, (3 \[Pi])/4, \[Pi]}}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"1:1", "1:2", "1:3", 
    "2:3"}, {0, \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/2, (3 \[Pi])/4, \[Pi]}}]`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
Grid[
 Transpose@
  Insert[
   Transpose@
    Insert[
     Table[
      aaa,
      {ab, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}}, {\[Phi], {0, \[Pi]/
         4, \[Pi]/2, (3 \[Pi])/4, \[Pi]}}], {0, \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/
       2, (3 \[Pi])/4, \[Pi]}, 1
     ],
   {
    Graphics[{
      Line[{{0, 1}, {2, 0}}],
      Text[Style["x:y", "StandardForm", Larger], {0.5, 0.25}],
      Text[Style["\[Phi]", "StandardForm", Larger], {1.5, 0.75}]
      },
     ImageSize -> Tiny],
    "1:1", "1:2", "1:3", "2:3"}, 1],
 Frame -> All
 ]
```

It's probably not the most robust solution in terms of scaling/spacing, but I think it comes close to what you wanted to achieve.

[image]

Comment: V10+ and we still have to do such silly acrobatics... (+1 ofc)

Comment: True, it does make one long for something like TikZ/PGF from time to time ;)

Comment: @Kuba Is there a system in which layout is not a pain?  Maybe publishers have such.  You can edit the graphics by hand and align the labels with the centers (using the Drawing Tools).  Like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xBpSu.png

Comment: @MichaelE2 you have the point. Maybe I have too much of a demanding attitude. But I really feel like some basic/standard grid layout solutions are expected to be built-in. There is something in Grid, something in TableForm, and with Graphics one can get some nice results. But I find it too much for a simple crude presentation of results.

Comment: @Kuba Well, I agree that *Mathematica* is a poor tool for layout and seems worse than it should be, imo. For the most part, I don't get irritated because I don't publish things that use scatter plots, legending, or tables.  So mostly, I just feel sorry for the users who have to meet publishers' style guides.

Comment: @Kuba I like your word "acrobatics" :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Well, I don't think adding a slash table head is to meet a publishers' style. It is needed when we want to present tables to other people clearly in mathematica. And if for publish, we have more Adobe Illustrator work to do :)

Answer (score 11):

There's [`Backslash`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Backslash.html):

```
Grid[Transpose@
  Insert[Transpose@
    Insert[Table[
      aaa,
      {ab, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}},
      {ϕ, {0, π/ 4, π/2, (3 π)/4, π}}],
    {0, π/4, π/2, (3 π)/4, π}, 1],
   {Backslash["x:y", ϕ], "1:1", "1:2", "1:3", "2:3"}, 1],
 Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use various things to control size and placement.  For instance, using

```
Backslash[Pane["x:y", ImageSize -> {Automatic, 30}, Alignment -> Bottom], ϕ]
```

results in

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

This looks a little better to me, but one can spend a lot of time fussing just to satisfy one's picayune aesthetic quirks.

```
Grid[Transpose@
  Insert[Transpose@
    Insert[Table[
      aaa,
      {ab, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}},
      {ϕ, {0, π/ 4, π/2, (3 π)/4, π}}],
    {0, π/4, π/2, (3 π)/4, π}, 1],
  {Backslash["x:y", Pane[ϕ, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 30}, Alignment -> Center]],
     "1:1", "1:2", "1:3", "2:3"}, 1], Frame -> All, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center, Table[{i, 1} -> ":", {i, 5}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]